# AWS Glue Pyspark Dataframe load into Snowflake. ON_ERROR = Continue and save the records into s3 location

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

Im trying load the Pyspark dataframe into snowflake from AWS Glue and I want to save the bad records which were failed to load should be tracked into AWS s3 location.

Bad records meaning if there are any datatype mismatches or length of data is different from the table schema.

```
df.write \
    .format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake") \
    .options(**snowflakeOptions) \
    .option("dbtable", "your_table") \
    .mode("append") \
    .option("sfOnError", "CONTINUE") \
    .option("sfErrorLimit", 0) \
    .option("sfErrorFile", "s3a://s3-bucket/error-records/error.csv") \
    .save()
```

im trying this but its not working. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue uses Snowflake's Spark connector to load data into a Snowflake table. The Spark connector triggers a COPY INTO which is actually a server-side SQL statement.

To continue loading records from a dataframe when an error occurred you have to set the parameter [`continue_on_error`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use#additional-options) to `on`. But this is still not solving your issue as in this case COPY INTO will just skip the row with the error and continue loading the rest of the rows.

There is no option as of now to unload the failed records to a separate file like you want.
On the other hand it is probably better to leave `continue_on_error` on `off` so you can actually see what kind of data issues you have on loading, otherwise you may have missing data.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is there any alternate way to achieve this requirment ?

Comment: What you want to do is probably a data type validation/transformation before load and that can be done by verifying that your Dataframe data types map correctly to your target table columns data types. You can use [Data Type Mappings](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use#data-type-mappings) from Snowflake Spark connector to see the exact mapping. You can also use a second approach by first loading to a temporary table in Snowflake (using AWS Glue with PySpark) and then validate data using Snowflake SQL (directly in Snowflake) before inserting to target table.